# How to load multiple excel files into different tables based on xls metadata using SSIS?

Tags: etl, ssis

I have multiple excel files with two types of metadata, Now i have to push the data into two different tables based on metadata of excel files using SSIS.

Answer (score 2):

There are many, many different ways to do this. You'd need to share a lot more information on how your data is structured to really give a great answer, but here's the general strategy I'd suggest.

In the control flow tab, have a separate data flow for each Excel file. The data flows will all work the same, with the exception of having a different Excel source in each data flow, so it will be enough to get the first version working and then copy and paste for the other files.

In the data flow, use a conditional split transformation to read the metadata coming from Excel and send the row to the correct table.

If you really want to be fancy, however, you could create a child package that includes all your data flow logic. Using the Execute Package Task you can pass the Excel file name to the child package for each Excel file you need to import. This way you consolidate your logic in one package and can still import from multiple Excel files in parallel.

Comment: Actually there are a set of .xls files which get uploaded in a folder frequently, I need to process those .xls files from the folder.
Now, I have a situation here where in this folder there are mainly two types of .xls in which depending upon the first column in the xls I need to decide which table it has to move the data (the filenames would be different).

I am stuck at this point where how do we determine the metadata from the xls files and point to the respective tables depending on the condition above.